# Segmentation fault on QTCreator with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, qt-creator

I'm testing the QTCreator IDE using the following program:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(){

    cv::imshow("My Image", 0);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

If I do the following:

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` main.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

The program run correctly. But If I use the `.pro` file and I do a make, I have a sefault error. The `.pro` is the following:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = qtTest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include/opencv2"

LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem some years ago. I do not know how and why, but this helps me. In your `.pro` file try to use

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

instead of

```
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

**EDIT**

I suspect, that the difference in your mode: normal or debug. I think the error comes right, but in the debug mode it was somehow passed through.

So try to compile and run you program in QT in debug mode (I expect that program will run correctly). Also, for comparission, try to compile and run your program with `g++` but without option `-ggdb`, I think you will receive that error.

Comment: Thank you for your help vz_, but I compiled the program with g++ without -ggdb and the program run correctly. I tried running the program by "debug mode" and I get this error: ``ptrace: Operation not permitted.

Could not attach to the process. Make sure no other debugger traces this process.
Check the settings of
/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf``

Comment: But there is something "weird"... when I run the program, but instead of qmake I use cmake everything is ok, and I can run it on QTCreator and in a console too...

Comment: For error with `ptrace` go to the `Projects -> Run` and uncheck `Run in terminal`. Regurding the program run from QT is strange. Perhaps your `qmake` use other compiler, look in the generated `Makefile` or in QT which compiler is used.

Comment: I did the first one(unchecking), then I got and error ``build-test-Desktop-Debug/qtTest...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/facu/qt-workspace/build-test-Desktop-Debug/qtTest exited with code 0``... Inside the makefile I have ``CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++``

Comment: Hmm... Strange... Have you tried to rebuild the program? Also try to run it in debug mode step by step from the first line in `main` to find the bug.

Comment: Yes I tried, I have got the following error: `The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault` It occurs instantly(I have a breakpoint at cv::imshow)

Comment: This is what I've got: http://pastebin.com/02iTdwzn(with Debugging starts
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n")

Comment: Sorry. I have no more idea. By me all runs ok from QT (QT 4.8.0, g++ 4.6.3). The last thing I can recommend is to reinstall your QT.

Comment: Hello vz_! I tried to compile it by creating a "NonQT-Project->Plain C++ Project" and it works well... Thank you for your help... I think the problem is "OpenCV/Highgui" uses QT, so if I make a QT Console project it chrashes... Did not find any other explanation

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your note. I will keep this in mind for future. This is weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For QT 5, build the OpenCV with QT=OFF. For QT 4, build the OpenCV with QT=ON.